# Android ViewPager and fragments design

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 fragments into it.
Everything works fine with two of them. 
The problem is with the third pager This one is a `TabHost`, in which there is one fragment in each tab.
But I've read that it's is not possible to put a `Tabhost` inside a Fragment. Nested fragments are forbidden.

Anyone has any idea of what can I do for resolving my problem?
Any alternatives?

Comment: Refer this post over [view pager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) and this post over [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and this [fragment tab pager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html).

Comment: Thanks Vineet, but I've already seen them. I think I'm going to change my design, but I don't know how. Thanks again anyway. I recommend these articles for learning how to use Fragments and ViewPagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i've done for resolving my problem.

I've done one "custom" Tabhost". I say "custom" because it is not a Tabhost, it seems to only.
In one of my fragements inside the ViewPager, i've 4 images on top of the fragment. And the rest of the fragment is one FrameLayout.
Each time i touch on the images, i replace the fragment which is in the frame for the respective fragemnt.

I add some code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="button1Click"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic1"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/text1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="button2Click"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic2"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/text2"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button3"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="button3Click"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic3"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/text3"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button4"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="button4Click"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic4"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/text4"/>
</LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layout_actual"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the FragmentActivity:

```
public void boton1Click(View v){
    mFragmentInViewPager.changeFragment(BUTTON1);
}

public void boton2Click(View v){
    mFragmentInViewPager.changeFragment(BUTTON2);
}

public void boton3Click(View v){
    mFragmentInViewPager.changeFragment(BUTTON3);
}
public void boton4Click(View v){
    mFragmentInViewPager.changeFragment(BUTTON4);
}
```

And finally in the FragmentInViewPager (the one which contains the other 4 fragments)

```
public void changeFragment(int fragmentId)
{
if(mCurrentFragmentId != fragmentId) {

switch(fragmentId) {
case BUTTON1:

    mFTransaction = mFManager.beginTransaction();
    mFTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_actual, mFragment1);
    mFTransaction.commit();
    mIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1_sel);
    mIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    mIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic3);
    mIv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic4);
    break;

case BUTTON2:
    mFTransaction = mFManager.beginTransaction();
    mFTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_actual, mFragment2);
    mFTransaction.commit();
    mIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    mIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2_sel);
    mIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic3);
    mIv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic4);
    break;

case BUTTON3:
    mFTransaction = mFManager.beginTransaction();
    mFTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_actual, mFragment3);
    mFTransaction.commit();
    mIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    mIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    mIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic3_sel);
    mIv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic4);
    break;

case BUTTON4:
    mFTransaction = mFManager.beginTransaction();
    mFTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_actual, mFragment4);
    mFTransaction.commit();
    mIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    mIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    mIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic3);
    mIv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic4_sel);
    break;

}

mCurrentFragmentId = fragmentId;
}

}
```

I hope of have explained myself well. If anyone needs more info, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the code as mentioned in this problem it will work as per your design.[Plese see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859425/fragment-is-not-restoring-its-state-in-a-viewpager-when-back-is-pressed-and-reop/9859727#comment12569510_9859727)